# What's wrong with the coding in my array?

Tags: c++, arrays

This is code I've written for an array that has 14 slots, each should have 4 in it except for the 6th and 13th slot, which are reverted back to 0. However, it doesn't compile. Does anyone know what I did wrong here?

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

const int MAX = 14;

int main ()
{
    void printArray ();

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}

void startArray (int beadArray[MAX])
{
    for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
        beadArray[i]=4;
    }
    beadArray[6]=0;
    beadArray[13]=0;
}

//**********************************************//

void printArray ()
{
    startArray (int beadArray[MAX]);
    for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
        cout<<i;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's horrible. :) A lot of problems with this code.

Comment: The awesome thing about when something doesn't compile is that **the compiler will say why**. And you don't even have to run the [not-built] target. Not only is this information **useful for you**, it is the *absolute minimum* required information **to make an acceptable question**.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reviewing code and is better suited for [Code Review](codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some corrected mistakes :

- declare your array outside startArray() function call if you want to use it outsite.
- pass the array as reference if you want to modify it
- cout << beadArray[i] instead of cout << i

.

```
using namespace std;    
#include <iostream>

const int MAX = 14;

int main ()    
{
    void printArray ();
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}

void startArray (int &beadArray[MAX])
{
    for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
        beadArray[i]=4;
    beadArray[6]=0;
    beadArray[13]=0;
}

//**********************************************//

void printArray ()
{
    int beadArray[MAX];
    startArray (beadArray);

    for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
        cout<<beadArray[i];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!
I made the corrections according to the input from all of the above, but now it doesn't output anything. My code looks like the code above, from gabitzish.

Comment: By the way, `int &beadArray[MAX]` is an array of references. You meant `int (&beadArray)[MAX]`.

Answer (score 7):

```
startArray (int beadArray[MAX]);
```

You're trying to declare `beadArray` and use it in one step. You should declare it before using it:

```
int beadArray[MAX];
startArray (beadArray);
```

You also have a multitude of other problems:

- `using namespace std;` has no effect because `<iostream>` hasn't been `#include`d yet. You shouldn't use a global `using namespace std;` as well.
- `system ("PAUSE");` should be replaced. I personally use:

  cin.sync();
  cin.get();
- the compiler doesn't know about the functions when in `main()`. Before `main()`, you should put prototypes:

  void printArray();
  void startArray (int []);
- in `main()` you say `void printArray();`. When calling a function, just use the function name and arguments:

  printArray();
- in `printArray()`, you're outputting `i` instead of `beadArray [i]`. There's also no spacing.
- global constants are a bad thing to use.

The fixed code I had looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

const int MAX = 14;

void startArray (int (&beadArray)[MAX]);
void printArray();

int main ()
{
    printArray ();

    std::cout << "\n\nPress enter to continue...";
    std::cin.sync();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}


void startArray (int (&beadArray)[MAX])
{
    for(int i=0; i<MAX; ++i)
        beadArray[i]=4;

    beadArray[6]=0;
    beadArray[13]=0;
}

void printArray ()
{
    int beadArray[MAX];
    startArray (beadArray);

    for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
        std::cout << beadArray[i] << ' ';
}
```

I did leave the constant in, but there's lots you can do to replace it.

Comment: isn't `void startArray (int beadArray[MAX])` going to copy the array and not modify the passed in array? Don't you need to take a reference or pointer?

Comment: @EdChum, it worked fine for me. I must admit I've never actually used a reference to an array. I've barely passed around arrays at all (minus in my class where not a mention was made about passing them by reference, or pointer) in favour of vectors or pointers.

Comment: @EdChum, I changed the final code to use a reference instead.

Comment: @chris I am surprised this worked, your function signature is taking a copy of an array and you pass this in, if it was a pointer to int and you passed the address of the int array then I would expect that to work, or you changed the function signature to take a reference to an array.

Comment: @EdChum, I like vectors. Less confusing ;) Though in this case a good old `std::array` is technically more suited.